# In Gorm Criteria: Filter collection inside domain by property

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria

I grais 2.4.3 I have

```
class DomainFather {
   Set domainSon = []
}
```

And

```
class DomainSon {
   Date dataCreated
}
```

And I'm trying in a gorm criteria:

```
def c = DomainFather.createCriteria()
def data = c.list {
    createAlias("domainSon", "ds")
    projections {
       max("ds.dataCreated", "ds")
    }
}
```

Obviously does not work, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to do this.
Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you didn't set up an association between the domain classes. Try this:

```
class DomainFather {

    static hasMany = [sons: DomainSon]

}
```

Then you'll be able to use a query:

```
def c = DomainFather.createCriteria()
def data = c.list {
    projections {
       sons {
           max("dataCreated")
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the real project I did, but i did not know about the projections { sons {.

Comment: Ah, ok. In Grails/GORM usually the alias is unnecessary. Having said that, an alias is needed when you need to use a different join type, such as a left outer join. http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-select-clause/